# According to Hegel, Heraclitus is

Tags: traducción

I want to translate [this sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Wilhelm_Friedrich_Hegel) into Spanish:

> According to Hegel, Heraclitus is the one who first declared the nature of the infinite and first grasped nature as in itself infinite.

My attempt:

> Según Hegel, Heráclito es la primera persona que declaró la naturaleza de lo infinito y la captó en sí mismo infinita.

Is my translation correct? 
If it's not , what would a native speaker suggest?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does "grasped nature as in itself infinite." means, who is itself

Comment: In this sentence, grasp means UNDERSTAND. understood nature como en si misma infinita. Hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Según Hegel, Heráclito es quien primero declara la naturaleza de lo
>   infinito así como quien primero capta la naturaleza misma como infinita.

EDIT: Is a matter of aesthetics how you link both "*Quien primero*". I have chosen "Así como".

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you a question? I translated in itself as en sí mismo. Is en sí mismo incorrect?

Comment: @keramus Sure. Why not?

Comment: Prefiero "declaró" and not "declara". I think it's better, "declara" sounds as speech and it's not so clear while reading.

Comment: Is a matter of taste. When you are enumerating a sequence of facts throughout a  span of time, you can conjugate everything in the present tense. Jorge Luis Borges was fond of that technique.

Answer (score 2):

This is my own translation, definitely it depends on aesthetics:

> Según Hegel, Heráclito fue el primero en declarar la naturaleza de lo infinito y el primero en...

That second part is a little bit hard for me to translate.